How to assign an id from the route to a command without duplicating it in the request body?
I have the following controller method in my ASP.NET Core application:
[HttpPost("{personId:guid}/workExperience")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddWorkExperienceAsync(
    [FromBody] AddWorkExperienceCommand command,
    [FromServices] IMediator mediator,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);

    return Created(nameof(GetByIdAsync), result);
}

In this method, the personIdis provided in the route (URL), but the AddWorkExperienceCommand class also contains a personId property that comes from the request body.
How can I map the personId from the route to the command object, so I don't have to include it in the request body as well?

Why do you have the personId field in the body when you also have the personId in the route?

I wanted to do the correct routing for my project and as far as I know the mediatr does not allow passing two or more parameters to the Handle method. I need personId to find person in database

You can use [JsonIgnore] attribute using System.Text.Json.Serialization as following
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class AddWorkExperienceCommand : IRequest
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guid personId { get; set; }

    //others
}

Then in your controller, assign personId from the route to PersonId in your command
[HttpPost("{personId:guid}/workExperience")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddWorkExperienceAsync(
    Guid personId,
    [FromBody] AddWorkExperienceCommand command,
    [FromServices] IMediator mediator,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    command.PersonId = personId;
    var result = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);

    return Created(nameof(GetByIdAsync), result);
}

Therefore, PersonId is assigned from the route and excluded from the request body
